# .NET 6 service registration works with concrete class but fails with interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I've got a class `ArtistAccess` that implements this interface in a .NET 6 minimal WebApi project:

```
using DataAccess.Models;

namespace DataAccess.Repository
{
    public interface IArtistAccess
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<Artist>> GetAllArtist();
        Task<int> Insert(Artist model);
    }
}
```

If I register the class as a concrete class, the app works:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ArtistAccess>();
```

If I register the class with the interface like this:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IArtistAccess, ArtistAccess>();
```

The app compiles but fails immediately at runtime with this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Body was inferred but the method does not allow inferred body parameters.
> Below is the list of parameters that we found:

Why doesn't the service registration work with the interface?

Comment: I run into the same issue …

Comment: PS: I have other apps where adding services with interfaces works like a champ.

Comment: Hi @rp. , I have tested your code in asp.net 6 and works fine... Could you please share the whole error message? And when do you get this error? When the app runs, it will appear in this line(AddSingleton)?

Comment: Where did this occur? This isn't a DI issue. Post the full exception text (ie including the call stack and any inner exceptions) and the actual location where the exception was thrown. On the other hand, the "generic repository" antipattern, especially with singleton lifetime, is going to cause far more serious problems.

Comment: The error complains about a method, not an interface. If you google the error message one of the first results is [this article](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-7-analyzers-for-minimal-apis/#-bind-isn-t-valid-on-minimal-apis) that explains that `Bind` can't be used in minimal APIs. The exception text gives a **very** detailed explanation. Is this the case here?

Comment: Does `Body` refer to the *request* body? In Andew Lock's article it's clear that the code is trying to bind an API parameter to the `Body` of the request, but this isn't allowed. `the method does not allow inferred body parameters.`

Comment: Have you changed the resolved parameter from `ArtistAccess` to `IArtistAccess` in your `MapGet` method?

Comment: Panagiotis--I don't think it's a DI issue directly, either. But It's how I register the service with .NET 6 DI that causes the problem. Registering the class as a concrete works fine, registering it with an interface is when the problem occurs. I am not using Bind.

Comment: Rena-- the error occurs at runtime and points to the line registers a method with a route. app.MapGet("/artist", GetAllArtist); GetAllArtist is a method in the ArtistAccess class. – 
rp.

Answer (score 2):

Doh. I @paul_shinn on Twitter found my mistake. If the service is registered as interface/class then route methods need to reference the interface, not the class.

Do this

```
    private static async Task<IResult> GetAllArtist(IArtistAccess data)
```

Instead of this:

```
    private static async Task<IResult> GetAllArtist(ArtistAccess data)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I meant in my comment about resolved parameter.

Comment: hi Roger, @paul_shinn here. don't forget to check your constructors too!